# Trying to capture or group txt from a string into a list box C#

Tags: c#

I have a .txt file containing many lines. I am trying to capture only lines that start with D. But here is the trick: I would like to also capture the 2 proceeding lines with it (When the D lines start) so I can capture what site and program this came from. Here is what I am looking for

**Desired result:**
![Text Desired][1]

Also, the D lines can appear multiple times in the text with varying length, so instead of 3 lines of "D" there could be 1000 or 10 or you get it..

How do I go about writing this, can this be done?
anel System Name:       BAUER Node 02
Program Name:            ABU.DEH1LR.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 02
Program Name:            ABU.RT1LR.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 02
Program Name:            ABU.RT2LR.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 02
Program Name:            ABU.RT3LR.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 03
Program Name:            ABA.LIGHTING.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 03
Program Name:            ABA.RT1LR.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 03
Program Name:            ABA.RT2LR.PGM
D     5205  LOOP(128 %X%SAT %X%VRT %X%SAS 1000 15 0 1 0 0 100 0)
D     5210  DBSWIT(0 ABA.RT2LR.HCO 2.0 8.0 ABA.RT2LR.HT1)
D     5220  TABLE(ABA.RT2LR.VRT %X%HCO 0 0 100 100)
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 03
Program Name:            ABA.RT3LR.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 03
Program Name:            ABA.ZONE.VLV.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 03
Program Name:            ABU.CAR.PLUG.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 04
Program Name:            ABA.RT4LR.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 04
Program Name:            BAUERBUSH PPCL 4
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 05
Program Name:            ABA.DEH1LR.PGM
Panel System Name:       BAUER Node 06
Program Name:            ABA.RT5LR.PGM

```
enter code here
```

Comment: We consider it very rude here to post an image instead of the text for your sample data. It also makes it harder for us to help you (we can't just copy/paste your data into a sample program to test it), meaning you are _much less likely to get a good answer_.

Comment: Noted...new here..makes sense now that it you put it that way. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to use code block properly in SO.

Comment: Thank you, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ListBox(Name:MainListBox) and Button(Name: GetTextButton) to Windows Form App
And use this codebehind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackAnswer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetTextButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var source = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test.txt");

            MainListBox.Items.Clear();

            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                if (source[i].StartsWith("D")
                    && !source[i - 1].StartsWith("D"))
                {
                    result.Add(source[i - 2]);
                    result.Add(source[i - 1]);
                    result.Add(source[i]);
                }
                else if (source[i].StartsWith("D"))
                {
                    result.Add(source[i]);
                }
            }
            MainListBox.Items.AddRange(result.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

WPF edition:

```
<Window x:Class="StackAnswerWPF.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackAnswerWPF" mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="283*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="37*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Name="MainListBox" />
        <Button Name="GetTextButton" Grid.Row="1" Click="GetText">GetText</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace StackAnswerWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test.txt");

            MainListBox.ItemsSource = null;

            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                if (source[i].StartsWith("D")
                    && !source[i - 1].StartsWith("D"))
                {
                    result.Add(source[i - 2]);
                    result.Add(source[i - 1]);
                    result.Add(source[i]);
                }
                else if (source[i].StartsWith("D"))
                {
                    result.Add(source[i]);
                }
            }
            MainListBox.ItemsSource = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Keep a buffer of the previous two lines.

Here's a sample that is typed directly into the reply window and is completely untested, and therefore likely has multiple bugs, but will still show conceptually what you need to do:

```
bool bufferready = false;
string prev1="", prev2="";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("path"))
{
   if (line.StartsWith("D"))
   {
       if (bufferready)
       {
           result.AppendLine(prev1);
           result.AppendLine(prev2);
           prev1 = "";
           prev2 = "";
           bufferready = false;
       }
       result.AppendLine(line);
   }
   else
   {
      prev1 = prev2;
      prev2 = line;
      bufferready = true;
   }
}
```

If you had provided sample data as text, instead of an image, I would have tried this in Visual Studio first and cleaned out any bugs before posting.